# adding multiple close menu links on push menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a push menu that comes out from the left and works great, but I'm struggling to apply more than one 'close-menu' link in the push menu.

I've tried changing the 'querySelector' to 'querySelectorAll' but that breaks the push menu.

The reason for this type of menu is because I will be using a content switcher, not going to another webpage.

A working version is available [here](http://markclaxton.co.uk/test/)

HTML JavaScript

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <header>
            <button id="c-button--push-left" class="c-button close-menu"></button>
        </header>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="c-menu--push-left" class="c-menu c-menu--push-left">
    <div class="c-menu__close close-menu"></div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a id="home" class="close-menu">Home</a></li>
            <li><a id="work" class="close-menu">Work</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<div id="c-mask" class="c-mask"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pushLeft = new Menu({
        wrapper: '#wrapper',
        type: 'push-left',
        menuOpenerClass: '.close-menu',
        maskId: '#c-mask',
    });
    var pushLeftBtn = document.querySelector('#c-button--push-left');
    pushLeftBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault;
        pushLeft.open();
    });

</script>
```

jQuery

```
 (function(window) {



'use strict';

  /**
   * Extend Object helper function.
   */
  function extend(a, b) {
    for(var key in b) { 
      if(b.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        a[key] = b[key];
      }
    }
    return a;
  }

  /**
   * Each helper function.
   */
  function each(collection, callback) {
    for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
      var item = collection[i];
      callback(item);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Menu Constructor.
   */
  function Menu(options) {
    this.options = extend({}, this.options);
    extend(this.options, options);
    this._init();
  }

  /**
   * Menu Options.
   */
  Menu.prototype.options = {
    wrapper: '#o-wrapper',          // The content wrapper
    type: 'slide-left',             // The menu type
    menuOpenerClass: '.c-button',   // The menu opener class names (i.e. the buttons)
    maskId: '#c-mask'               // The ID of the mask
  };

  /**
   * Initialise Menu.
   */
  Menu.prototype._init = function() {
    this.body = document.body;
    this.wrapper = document.querySelector(this.options.wrapper);
    this.mask = document.querySelector(this.options.maskId);
    this.menu = document.querySelector('#c-menu--' + this.options.type);
    this.closeBtn = this.menu.querySelector('.close-menu');
    this.menuOpeners = document.querySelectorAll(this.options.menuOpenerClass);
    this._initEvents();
  };

  /**
   * Initialise Menu Events.
   */
  Menu.prototype._initEvents = function() {
    // Event for clicks on the close button inside the menu.
    this.closeBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.close();
    }.bind(this));

    // Event for clicks on the mask.
    this.mask.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.close();
    }.bind(this));
  };

  /**
   * Open Menu.
   */
  Menu.prototype.open = function() {
    this.body.classList.add('has-active-menu');
    this.wrapper.classList.add('has-' + this.options.type);
    this.menu.classList.add('is-active');
    this.mask.classList.add('is-active');
    this.disableMenuOpeners();
  };

  /**
   * Close Menu.
   */
  Menu.prototype.close = function() {
    this.body.classList.remove('has-active-menu');
    this.wrapper.classList.remove('has-' + this.options.type);
    this.menu.classList.remove('is-active');
    this.mask.classList.remove('is-active');
    this.enableMenuOpeners();
  };

  /**
   * Disable Menu Openers.
   */
  Menu.prototype.disableMenuOpeners = function() {
    each(this.menuOpeners, function(item) {
      item.disabled = false;
    });
  };

  /**
   * Enable Menu Openers.
   */
  Menu.prototype.enableMenuOpeners = function() {
    each(this.menuOpeners, function(item) {
      item.disabled = false;
    });
  };

  /**
   * Add to global namespace.
   */
  window.Menu = Menu;

})(window);
```

Comment: could you please create a fiddle with your files at http://jsfiddle.net. I've tried but you are loading lots of things (3 CSS files). Also the code above looks like prototype but you tagged jQuery, are u using both? what so ever. the problem begins here `this.closeBtn = this.menu.querySelector('.close-menu');`  this is expecting the `.close-menu` to be a `menu` which #home and #work are not

Comment: It's from a push menu tutorial found on  http://callmenick.com/post/slide-and-push-menus-with-css3-transitions

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c4udhs9w/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `querySelectorAll` and in `Menu.prototype._initEvents` use this code to iterate over closeBtn, and since it's array you should probably rename it to *closeButtons* or so.

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.closeBtn.length; ++i) {
  this.closeBtn[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.close();
  }.bind(this));    
}
```

Comment: Any chance can show me on https://jsfiddle.net/c4udhs9w/ i'm not entirely confident in my javascript skills.

Comment: Thanks! That is brilliant.